# Coq Induction on Hypothesis destroys the Hypothesis

Tags: coq, inductive-type, induction, prop

I'm trying to prove something in coq 
I have and Inductive prop type named in_order_merge which is a relation between three lists that shows third one is in_order merge of first two, here is the definition.

```
Inductive in_order_merge {X : Type} : list X -> list X -> list X -> Prop :=
  | iom_nil : in_order_merge [ ] [ ] [ ]
  | iom_merge_l x l1 l2 l (H: in_order_merge l1 l2 l) :
  in_order_merge (x :: l1) l2 (x :: l)
  | iom_merge_r x l1 l2 l (H: in_order_merge l1 l2 l) :
  in_order_merge l1 (x :: l2) (x :: l).
```

I want to prove that if one of the lists is empty then this preposition means the non-empty one equals the third list. clearly induction on hypothesis (constructors) is the way to go but my problem comes when i get to second constructor and the fact that one of the lists is empty is completely demolished.
here is the lemma and it's proof:

```
Lemma iom_l_nil: forall X : Type, forall l2 l : list X, in_order_merge [ ] l2 l -> l2 = l.
Proof. intros. induction H. 
  - reflexivity.
  - admit.
  - rewrite IHin_order_merge. reflexivity.
Admitted.
```

and this is my proof-view on second branch:

```
X: Type
x: X
l1, l2, l: list X
H: in_order_merge l1 l2 l
IHin_order_merge: l2 = l
```

---

```
1/1
l2 = x :: l
```

can anyone help me with what i can do to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `induction` tactic tends to forget about the values of concrete arguments (e.g., `nil` on `in_order_merge`.) One possible fix is to use `remember` to convert the `nil` argument to a variable:

```
Lemma iom_l_nil {X} (xs ys : list X) : in_order_merge nil xs ys -> xs = ys.
  intros H.
  remember nil as l.
  (* now, H as type in_order_merge l xs ys; this is good for induction *)
  induction H.
  - auto. (* base case *)
  - discriminate Heql. (* left case:  l <> nil *)
  - rewrite IHin_order_merge; auto. (* right case *)  
Qed.
```

Alternatively, you can structure the proof as inductive on the second argument itself, rather than on the proof of `in_order_merge`:

```
Lemma iom_l_nil {X} (xs ys : list X) : in_order_merge nil xs ys -> xs = ys.
  revert ys. (* generalize the induction hypothesis over ys *)
  induction xs; intros ys Hys. (* Hys is the proof of in_order_merge *)
  - inversion Hys; subst; auto. (* case xs = nil *)
  - inversion Hys; subst; rewrite (IHxs _ H3); auto. (* case xs not nil *)
Qed.
```

The `inversion` tactic is very useful here, since the branch of `in_order_merge` is uniquely determined by whether `xs` is nil or a cons (since the first argument is `nil`).

Comment: Instead of reverting and reintroducing `ys`, Coq provides the equivalent but slighthly nicer syntax `induction xs in ys |- *`.